# R: making a hard-to-describe transformation to a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Right now I have a dataset that roughly looks like this:

```
Id    Eng_ver_1    Eng_ver_2    Bio_ver_1     Bio_ver_2    Subject    Version

1      NA             1            NA             NA         Eng       2
2      NA            NA            NA             1          Bio       2
3      NA            NA             1             NA         Bio       1
4      1             NA            NA             NA         Eng       1
```

The columns represent conditions that participants go through. Because each person only goes through one condition, it is guaranteed that in every row only 1 of the 4 columns has a value. Instead of looking like this, it is easier to do analysis in my case if the data were to look like this:

```
Id    Subject    Version   Score
1     English     2         1
2     Biology     2         1
3     Biology     1         1
4     English     1         1
```

Is there any quick way of doing this transformation? In other words, how do I get rid of all the NAs and shrink the 4 columns into 1.

Additionally, What if instead of 4 columns, I have 40 columns, with each Id only having data in 10 out of those 40 columns?

Comment: `df$Score <- rowSums(df[2:5], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   transmute(Id, Subject, Version, 
         score  =  coalesce(!!! select(., contains('ver'))))
#   Id Subject Version score
#1  1     Eng       2     1
#2  2     Bio       2     1
#3  3     Bio       1     1
#4  4     Eng       1     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:4, Eng_ver_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), Eng_ver_2 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA), Bio_ver_1 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA), Bio_ver_2 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), Subject = c("Eng", "Bio", "Bio", "Eng"), Version = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks. Coalesce() ended up helping me. I noticed it can also do the same thing with several dataframes, going col by col in each and finding the first non NA value

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll have data in only one column in each row I think using `rowSums` as suggested by @alistaire would be easy and quick solution.

You can also get data in long format with `pivot_longer` in `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = matches('.*_ver_\\d+'), 
                      values_drop_na = TRUE, values_to = 'score') %>%
  select(-name)


# A tibble: 4 x 4
#     Id Subject Version score
#  <int> <chr>     <int> <int>
#1     1 Eng           2     1
#2     2 Bio           2     1
#3     3 Bio           1     1
#4     4 Eng           1     1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:4, Eng_ver_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), Eng_ver_2 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA), Bio_ver_1 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA), Bio_ver_2 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), Subject = c("Eng", "Bio", "Bio", "Eng"), Version = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```